# Auto-adjusting textarea to be the same height as inner-text onkeydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to auto adjust the height of a textarea onkeydown, but it's only working partially. When you're typing text into the textarea, it auto-adjust the height of the textarea per new line of text, which is what I want. But when you're backspacing the text, it auto-adjust the height of the textarea per character-backspaced when you're on the last 5 characters of every last line. What am I doing wrong?

```
#textarea { 
overflow: hidden; 
} 

<textarea id = 'textarea' onkeydown = "adjust()"></textarea> 

<script> 
function adjust() { 

document.getElementById("textarea").style.height = document.getElementById("textarea").scrollHeight+'px'; 

} //end of function adjust() 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your textarea:

```
<textarea id="textarea" onkeyup="InputAdjust(this)"></textarea>
```

then create a function to do the auto height

```
<script>
    function InputAdjust(o) {
        o.style.height = "1px";
        o.style.height = (25+o.scrollHeight)+"px";
    }
</script>
```

now its +25px, you can change it.

example: https://jsfiddle.net/urp4nbxf/1/

Comment: Why do you set the `height` to `1px` first?

Comment: i did use this function in an angular - ionic project. so i use it to fix the height because it was problem maker if not and this solve it.

Comment: It's onkeydown, not onkeyup. Also, the textarea auto-adjust in the middle of typing the letters, and not when the letter is typed on the next new line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#textarea").on("keydown",function(){
    if($(this).css("height").replace("px","") <        $('#textarea').get(0).scrollHeight - 5) 
  $(this).css("height",($('#textarea').get(0).scrollHeight-5) + "px"); 
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/dpx1Ltn2/2/

Comment: Guess it needed minor alterations, fixed now.

Comment: What is wrong with the original code itself, in my example above?

Comment: Also, there are 2 problems with this. The first being that while the textarea grows bigger when you're typing text in it, it does not shrink when you're backspacing. The second problem is less important right now.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will work, but you will have to manually count how many characters fit in per row, in the textarea. How many characters fit in per row will depend on the cols of the textarea, and of course the font-size of the text.

```
#textarea {
overflow: hidden;
}

<textarea id = 'textarea' cols = '7' rows = '1' onkeydown = "adjust()"></textarea>

<script>

function adjust() {

var maxCharactersPerColumn = 9; //You have to manually count how many characters fits in per row

var key = event.keyCode;
if (key == 8 || key == 46) {
var length = document.getElementById("textarea").value.length-2;
} //end of if (key == 8 || key == 46)
else {
var length = document.getElementById("textarea").value.length;
} //end of else !(key == 8 || key == 46)

var rows = Math.floor(length/maxCharactersPerColumn)+1;
document.getElementById("textarea").rows = rows; 

} //end of function adjust()
</script>
```

Comment: unfortunately this would fail if you resize the textarea.